# Access boostrap dropdown value in JS when multiple dropdowns rendered

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, google-cloud-firestore, drop-down-menu

- In javascript, I have multiple rows rendered to the DOM from a Firebase/Firestore collection.
- In each row, a Bootstrap dropdown is created with always the same select-options (.a elements).
- The id attribute of each row div is set dynamically based on the
  Firestore doc.id.
- I would like to get the selected value from the dropdown of one
  specific row when the user clicks it in the dropdown list.

This is my code:

```
    //get Firestore collection
    db.collection('collection1').get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {

      //create row to be rendered...
      let row = document.createElement('div');
      let container = document.getElementById('myContainer');

      //...append it to the container element
      container.appendChild(row);

      //set row id to the doc.id for future access
      row.setAttribute('id', doc.id);


      //bootstrap dropdown rendered here
      document.getElementById(doc.id).innerHTML =
        '<span class="font-weight-bolder border rounded p-2 dropdown-toggle" id="selectStatus' +doc.id+ ' "  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">' + doc.data().status+ '</span>'
        +
        '<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="selectStatus' + doc.id + '">' +
        '    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>' +
        '    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>' +
        '    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>' +
        '  </div>';

       }); 
    });
```

I have tried this:

```
$('#someId a').on('click', function(){
$('#someOtherId').val($(this).html());
});
```

and other solutions in other posts but from what I understand they always refer to one single Dropdown element. In my case there are multiple rows rendered with one dropdown element each, and the dropdown id changes of course for each row.

Any hint would be really helpful!

Comment: It looks like you have a mix of Vanilla JavaScript and jQuery here. On the jQuery part of your code, `$(this)` should refer to the clicked element - the one that fired the event. What's going wrong then?

Comment: You should be able to select the dropdown using `$('#' + doc.id).find('.dropdown-menu')`

Comment: Also, it's worth it mentioning that you're listening to click events coming from hyperlinks, so you need to prevent the default behavior, which is navigate somewhere else.

Comment: Observe the element's class and you can forget about looking into Ids - ie: `$('a.dropdown-item').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault();  $('#someOtherId').val($(this).html()); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the IDs and observe the hyperlinks class when handling the click event:

Using jQuery:

```
$('a.dropdown-item').on('click', function(e) { 
    // You don't want to navigate away from this page I suppose?
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#someOtherId').val($(this).text());
});
```

Using Vanilla JavaScript (ES6):

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item");

const myHandler = (e) => {
    // You don't want to navigate away from this page I suppose?
    e.preventDefault();

    const myElement = document.getElementById("someOtherId");
    
    myElement.value = this.text;
};

Array.from(elements).forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', myHandler);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help! But I realise I'm really lost here, and I have very little knowledge of jquery so I would prefer using vanilla JS. I have the feeling using class instead of ID is the right way in deed, but I can't even make this work when placed in a .then() method after the collection.get method                                      
             `document.querySelectorAll('div.dropdown-menu > a').addEventListener('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('hello')
            })`                                 Only the href link triggers.

Comment: OK so this solution definately works, I don't know what I did wrong. I get the innertHTML like so: `$('a.dropdown-item').on('click', function(e) { 
    // You don't want to navigate away from this page I suppose?
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).text())
});` Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Now I can see you wanted the hyperlink text then? If so I'm gonna update my answer to reflect it.

Comment: I've also added the same code but using Vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Wow great! Now I also understand the logic of it in vanillaJS, thanks!!!